# What would you suggest I change in these lines of code?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to make this clear*(So people dont rush to downvote this because it is easy for them.*):
**I am a beginner programmer and yes I will move to mysqli after I finish some basic stuff and about pdo no it is to complicated for me.**

```
require('header.php');
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$userRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = $id AND visible = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($userRow);
$user_1 = $row['id'];
if ($user_1)
{
    echo function($user_1);
}else{
     echo 'Error 404';
}
```

How I avoid sql injection from this code and any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is the way to do it when you don't use prepared statements.

Comment: so if you don't want to use PDO how do you gonna use prepared method?

Comment: @DevMan mysqli has prepared statements.

Comment: PDO isn't any more complicated than mysqli.

Comment: You'd be better skipping mysql and jumping straight to mysqli or PDO if you're just beginning (with prepared statements/bind variables), better to learn the right way from the start, rather than to have to unlearn later.

Comment: @MarkBaker I think the problem with that advice is that I'll bet most of the tutorial sites still use mysql.

Comment: Use to oop way of mysqli than you can use mysqli::prepare. By the way, don't use mysql ! use mysqli.

Comment: @DevMan Use the procedural way of mysqli then you can use `mysqli_prepare()`.

Comment: To answer the question in some manner: [`intval()`](https://php.net/intval) instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Use a plain text file instead of MySQL

Comment: use Doctrine, use LessQL, use NotORM, use jQuery

Comment: You should also check whether `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returned something, with `if($row)` before `$user_1 = $row['id']`

Comment: can you make edit the question and do it in right way (mysqli way)

Comment: Questions asking for commentary on coding style and correctness are more appropriate for CodeReview.stackexchange.com. Use SO when you're having trouble getting the program to work correctly and you need help fixing it.

Comment: The answer is in the question. Switch to mysqli AND use prepared statements

Answer (score 3):

Using the mysql extension in PHP is deprecated since PHP 5.5 - even if you are just starting to use PHP/MySQL, these functions should not be your starting point. The minimum should be mysqli. Most functions with `mysql_` have a `mysqli_` equivalent.

Generally, you should try to reduce the attack surface by whitelisting allowed values:

1. If your ID is an integer, then typecast it, for example with: `` $userRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = " . intval($_GET['id']) . " AND visible = 1"); `` This eliminates all SQL injections for this query.
2. If only alphanumeric characters are allowed, use a simple regular expression, something like `` $userRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = \"" . preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $_GET['id']) . "\" AND visible = 1"); `` - everything except A-Z, a-z and 0-9 is removed from the string.
3. If your ID is an email address or another predefined format, use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) - only execute the query if the input you receive passes the filter_var successfully.
4. If some characters are specifically not allowed in a string which could lead to SQL injection, strip them no matter how you escape your string, for example with `$id = mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace('[\'"]', '', $_GET["id"]));` or `$id = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('"', '', str_replace('\'', '', $_GET["id"])));` - this removes any " and ' from the string, which are not typically needed.
5. If any string is allowed (this should be a small minority of cases in most applications), `mysqli_real_escape_string` is a good choice. In your example you still need quotes around the $id, for example `` $userRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = '$id' AND visible = 1"); `` The tricky part is that `mysqli_real_escape_string` depends on the used charset - also use `mysqli_set_charset()` and set it to utf8.

As you see, you need a lot of thought and care to do this yourself - this is not worth it in my opinion. Use an existing library or framework, where a lot of thought went into preventing SQL injection, and where there is detailed documentation to avoid security flaws. Doctrine is a good choice (with DBAL you can still do queries yourself with minimal overhead). You can still wrap these libraries in your own objects or classes, to have full control.

PDO is not hard, if you want to use only built-in methods of PHP. This is an example with unnamed placeholders:

```
$db = new PDO("dbtype:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");

$insecuredata = $_GET["id"];

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND visible = 1");
$query->execute(array($insecuredata));
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This example uses named parameters, which makes it easy to extend the query (there are several ways of doing this, $query->bindParam is also a good possibility - see PHP documentation for [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php)):

```
$db = new PDO("dbtype:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");

$insecuredata = $_GET["id"];

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id AND visible = 1");
$query->execute(array(':id' => $insecuredata));
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Get used to the possibilities PHP and existing frameworks give you - they all went through a long learning process to eliminate problems and security flaws. Do you really want to learn all possible problems the hardest way?

Comment: You might want to modify the PDO method by adding a bind. Might be clearer for him.

Comment: I added an example with named parameters - this is a good addition and maybe easier to modify.